# Select an option in a dropdown box and display its associated data in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

1. How to select a supplement and display its associated data such as its description and cost.
2. Any help will be appreciated.

> PHP:

```
require('database.php');

$suppID = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'suppID');

if($suppID==null || $suppID==false){
    $suppID = 'Supplement-1';
}

$query = 'select * from tblsupplements where Supplement_id= :SupplementID';
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement = bindValue(':SupplementID', $suppID);
$statement->execute();
$supplements = $statement->fetchAll();
$statement->closeCursor();
```

> HTML:

```
<label>Supplement ID:</label>
<select name='suppID'>
<?php foreach ($supplements as $supplement): ?>          
<option value="<?php echo $supplement['Supplement_id']; ?>">
<?php echo $supplement['Supplement_id']; ?>
</option>         
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Display __where__? In popup? In some div? In another inputs?

Comment: Sorry bro! Basically on the same page in a label something like: <p><label>Cost</label> then php echo supplement['cost'];</p>

Comment: Javascript is used for this.

Comment: Thanks will try javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, hopefully helps.

```
<label>Supplement ID:</label>
<select name='suppID'>
<?php foreach ($supplements as $supplement) {
    echo "<option value='".$supplement['Supplement_id']."'>".$supplement['Supplement_id']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks. i will try it.